# How to create an 'onclick' function?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I want to create an 'onclick' function.
That is what I was able to do with the help from Youtube.
Now I would like to add a function that when I click on the gray field, another  container moves to the right with 50% width. I would like to fill this div with text and pictures. 
Sorry for my bad english, I hope you guys understand what I want

```css
.news {
position: fixed;
display: block;
width: 33.33%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
background-color: grey;;
background-size: auto, cover;
transition: width 0.5s;
}

.open{
width: 50%;
transition: width 0.5s;
position: fixed;
display: block;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
background-color: grey;
background-size: auto, cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
<script>
    function toggleClass (el) {
        
        if(el.className == "news"){
  el.className = "open";
 } else {
  el.className = "news";
 }
        
    }
</script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="news" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice Title Man.

Comment: By hard work, nose on a good book.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the innerHTML property where you can add your text

```
el.innerHTML = 'text'
```